# OpenCV: cvCloneImage and memory leak

Tags: opencv, iplimage

I am very new to OpenCV. I noticed the following code has a memory leak:

```
IplImage *img, *img_dest;
img = cvLoadImage("..\\..\\Sunset.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
while(1) // to make the mem leak obvious
{
    img_dest = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    img_dest = cvCloneImage(img);
    cvReleaseImage( &img_dest );
}
cvReleaseImage( &img );
```

How to release the unreferenced data then? And is there an easy way to make a clean copy of an IPL image (of course we could write a loop to copy each element of the data...).

Comment: It's worth noting that using `cv::Mat` instead of `IplImage*` is preferred in C++, as it avoids having these pointer references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your memory leak issue:

`cvCreateImage` allocated memoryA for the image, and `cvCloneImage` allocated memoryB (and cloning whatever value stored in `img` as stated in your code). `cvReleaseImage(&img_dest)` only deallocate memoryB thus memoryA is left unreferenced but not deallocated.

For your IPL Image copying:

Declare another memory and use command `cvCopy`, i dont see any difficulties in using it and it is safe and efficient.

If you wish to declare an IPL image header without allocating data byte for storing image value, use `CreateImageHeader` instead. I would advise you to spend some time mastering `cvCreateImage`, `cvCreateImageHeader`, `cvCreateData`, `cvReleaseImage`, `cvReleaseImageHeader`, `cvReleaseImageData` and `cvCloneImage`.